# Align environment: Numbering equations by line

Tags: align, numbering

The standard behaviour of align is to give every line a new number, where the numbering is global (or per chapter). Is it possible, to give each align environment only one number, and number each line by a local counter.

It's probably more clear, if I give an example:
[image: example]

Here the first one is the standard behaviour and the second one is the desired one (I set the numbers via the \tag command).
It would be best, if equation environments (or environments with only one line) would be numbered as usual.

Comment: So would the `1.` prefix be anything specific/existing in the document? Or is it a number associated with each `align`? What would happen when you have only one equation (and therefore not an `align`, but an `equation` instead)... what should the numbering look like then?

Comment: @Werner Yes, 1. would be the standard equation number, i.e. \theequation. In an equation environment I would prefer only the prefix, so (2) instead of (2.1) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution surrounds every `align` with `\begin{subequations}`...`\end{subequations}` and also redefines the way sub-equations are numbered - `<parent>.<eqn>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{environ,amsmath}

\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

% Needs LaTeX2e 2020-10-01 or later 
\AddToHook{env/align/before}{%
  \begin{subequations}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}%
}
\AddToHook{env/align/after}{%
  \end{subequations}
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}
\chapter{A chapter}

\[ f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \]

\begin{equation} f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \end{equation}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
\end{align*}

\[ f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \]

\begin{equation} f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \end{equation}

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```